# BQ Aquaris X5 - Unable to mount sd card rw via USB

Tags: cyanogenmod, sd-card

I just bought a new Aquaris X5 with Cyanogen OS from BQ and inserted the freshly formatted sd card into the phone. When I am connecting the phone via USB cable with my Fedora laptop, I am able to view the contents of the SD Card, but it's impossible to write files there. The card is freshly formatted but Cyanogen OS created some folders there:

- Android
- LOST.DIR

For testing purposes I connected the phone to a Windows 7 Laptop -> same result, but of course a less verbose error message. This is the error message from my Fedora kernel:

```
[ 4699.538538] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 4699.538543] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 4699.538546] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Write error - auto reallocation failed
[ 4699.538549] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 08 01 00 00 01 00
[ 4699.538551] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2049
[ 4699.538554] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 1, lost async page write
```

In Cyanogen OS I configured in the Settings -> Storage menu that the Phone should be connected as a Mass Storage Device (UMS). When I change the connection type to MTP device I am able to correctly transfer files to the phone. I am also able to create new folders and files with the file manager on the phone. So there is apparently nothing wrong with the SD Card and hardware of the phone.

Any ideas how to fix this? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, use the tool [gMTP](http://gmtp.sourceforge.net/) (available from the standard repos of most distributions as package `gmtp`). Then it works. I also have a Aquaris X5 with Cyanogen OS.